# My program crashes when i try to run it and i cant find why?

Tags: c, file, linked-list, structure

I have a project for school and my task is to read from file and then make the information as data structure:

```
S 123456 Ivan
S 654321 Georgi
T 123456 Jesper
T 123457 Ole
T 123458 Lars
T 123459 Erland
C 31 CALI1 3
C 11 WDDI1 1
C 21 SDJI2 2
E 123456 31
E 123456 11
E 654321 21
A 123456 31
A 123457 11
```

The letters on each row refer to a the type of the data , everything else is information related to the struct, such name , ID and so on.
The only wrong thing is the reading from file part because thats where the program crashes 
There is my code for it:

```
  void my_fct() {
#define SIZE_LINE 256
    char* line = "";
    FILE *ifile = fopen_s(&stream5,"input.txt", "r");
    if (ifile != NULL) {
        while (fgets(line, SIZE_LINE, ifile)) {




            if (sscanf_s(line, "T ") == 2) {

                int number;
                char* name = "";
                sscanf_s(line, "T %d %s", &number, name,55);
                add_teacher(name, number);
            }



            if (sscanf_s(line, "S ") == 2) {

                int number;
                char* name = "";
                sscanf_s(line, "S %d %s", &number, name,55);
                add_student(name, number);
            }

            if (sscanf_s(line, "C  ") == 2) {

                int number;
            char* name="";
                int sem;
            sscanf_s(line, "C %d %s %d", &number, name, &sem, 55);
                add_course(number, name, sem);
            }


            if (sscanf_s(line, "A  ") == 2) {
                int number;
                int numb;
                sscanf_s(line, "A %d %d", &number, &numb,55);
                add_assignment(number, numb);

            }

            if (sscanf_s(line, "E ") == 2) {
                int number;
                int numb;
                sscanf_s(line, "E %d %d", &number, &numb,55);
                add_enrolment(number, numb);

            }

        }
        fclose(ifile);
    }
}
```

Comment: [fopen_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) return `errno_t`, not `FILE*`.

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, as this question is asking. post a [mcve].

Comment: when calling `sscanf_s()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the code is not correct for `sscanf_s()`  the expected returned value is not correct.  Here is a quote from the MAN page: *Each of these functions returns the number of fields that are successfully converted and assigned; the return value does not include fields that were read but not assigned. A return value of 0 indicates that no fields were assigned. The return value is EOF for an error or if the end of the string is reached before the first conversion.*

Comment: this kind of a statement: `if (sscanf_s(line, "A  ") == 2)` is not correct.  Suggest: `if( strncmp( line, "A ", 2 ) == 0 )`

Comment: would it be nice to inform the user of the details of a problem if the call to `fopen_s()` fails,  perhaps with `FILE *stream5;  if( (  fopen_s( &stream5, "input.txt",  "r" ) ) { perror( "fopen_s to read 'input.txt' failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }  // implied else, fopen_s successful`

Comment: this line: `while (fgets(line, SIZE_LINE, ifile))` should be: `while (fgets(line, SIZE_LINE, stream5))`

Comment: strongly suggest placing `#define` statements between functions rather than inside the body of functions.